# Parse recursively unknown JSON structure with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I try to parse a JSON structure with JSON.NET. All properties of the first level is deserializing correctly.

I have a problem to deserialize a Dictionary. The object type can be anything: string, double, int, bool, List, Dictionary and recursively.

Example JSON:

```
 {
     "id":"56d4f8sd4f86ds4f",
     "name":"Azerty",
     "dynProp": {
         "xp":100,
         "life":100,
         "bonus": {
             "force": 100,
             "defense": 100
         },
         "ennemies": {
             "beast": {
                 "wolf": 100,
                 "bear": 20
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

All datas in the dynProp node is dynamic and I can't know the object type, the depth or anything.

The ouput for the dynProp object is something like that:

```
{{"dynProp","{xp:100, life: 100, bonus: {...}, ...}"}}
```

In fact, JSON.NET put in the object value the jobject and not at all inners dictionaries or stuff like that.

I try to add Serialization Settings like that:

```
new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
        TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
    }
```

But with no success...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: I'm open to another framework but it must work on .net 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is explicitly about JSON.NET but in the hopes that you don't know about the awesome ServiceStack library, I'd like to add a recommendation that you move to that instead. Specifically, the ServiceStack.Text namespace has a JSON Serializer that's [much faster than JSON.NET's serializer](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344).

In addition, they have a JSONObject.Parse method that handles your use case better (I believe). See this stack overflow post which pretty much matches what you are looking for:

[ServiceStack.Text.JsonObject.Parse vs. NewtonSoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse for nested tree of 'dynamic' instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366387/servicestack-text-jsonobject-parse-vs-newtonsoft-json-linq-jobject-parse-for-ne)

Comment: Sorry! I didn't realize you were on 2.0, ServiceStack does 3.5+ according to their site. :(

Comment: No problem. I not mention it. It's my fault! ;)